# Keeping comma in the text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, number-formatting

I am trying give decimal value to input field like - 10,235,333. It takes this value but as I move to next field, commas are removed from text field. Is there any way that commas will be left in the text field until I submit the form but when I submit the form only numbers will be stored in the database?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: will you please show some part of your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got the solution for this issue. I got a jquery plugin for this  that is [**jquery.number**](https://github.com/customd/jquery-number). This plugin automatically adds comma to your numbers.

This plug-in formats input value implicitly.

like if we type

```
10000 it formats this no to 10,000
for 1000 = 1,000
for 100000 = 100,000
for 1000000 = 1,000,000
```

Answer (score 1):

you can override the setter method. Given a price field,

```
# model
def price=(num)
  write_attribute :price, price.gsub(/[^\d]/, '')
end
```

Then in your view, you can format the value before you render the view

```
f.text_field :price, value: number_with_delimiter(f.object.price)
```